# VS Code extension that show a model properties

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know about a VS Code extension that let me see the properties of a model from the HTML markup?
For example, on ngModel, i write my binded and press dot (.) so it will open its properties (like when I do on ts file).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Angular Language Service extension, i think it gives you what you require. You can check it out,
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

I hope it will help you...

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Why it should be a comment and not an answer?

Comment: This is an answer since it answers the question. It looks like a simple equation

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) will help you.